# Execute a NodeJS package from GitHub

Tags: node.js

I will be obliged if somebody can guide me as to running the code over [this page](https://github.com/cscape/vitalsource-dl). The Readme file does not provide any minimal hint.

I have never used NODEJS or other programming languages and have had minimal interactions with C, years back.

Comment: I am sorry for asking a basic question. Does a (-1) mean that I ought to delete this?

Comment: Have you considered doing any tutorials before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `npm install` after you can run `npm start`.